# I want clear the cookies of a page when loading from another page but not when the same page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I am building a new website and for this I have created a page which has an array store in cookies and I am clearing that array by using

$.removeCookie("checkboxValues");

I am running this function when document gets ready. When I am coming to this page from another page using link I want to clear the cookies and yes that is happening. But my problem is if I load the same page (using f5 or ctrl + r) the cookies gets cleared and I don't want to loose that cookies. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: check with your page url if its in same page don't removeCookie

Comment: @jagadeesh..it;s not work cause when it redirect from other page it has the same page url which he get at tym of refresh

Comment: how about using `localStorage` instead of `cookies`?

Comment: @Guruprasad Thanks for comments, but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with one of below:

> the easiest way I can think of to achieve this would be to put a
>   time-stamp in the query string of the redirect and read this in
>   JavaScript. Set a cookie with this time stamp and detect whether it
>   already exists to tell whether the page is being reloaded (has been
>   loaded with the query-string before).

**Code :**

Store a cookie the first time someone visits the page. On refresh check if your cookie exists and if it does, alert.

```
function checkReload() {
  if(document.cookie.indexOf('YOURCOOKIE')==-1) {
    // cookie doesn't exist, create it now
  }
  else {
    // not first visit, so alert
    alert('You refreshed!');
  }
}
```

and in your body tag:

```
<body onload="checkReload()">
```

**One More :**

First step is to check sessionStorage for some pre-defined value and if it exists alert user:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("is_reloaded")) alert('Reloaded!');
```

Second step is to set sessionStorage to some value (for example true):

```
sessionStorage.setItem("is_reloaded", true);
```

Session values kept until page is closed so it will work only if page reloaded in a new tab with the site.

Comment: Hi hardy, I appreciate your help but I want to clear cookies  every time when some one is loading that page using link from another page. But never when he will refresh.